# Formato de Data diferente

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Senhores,
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
            $funcionario_blocodcon_novo = array();
            for($i=0;$i<count($funcionario_blocodcon['localtrabalho']);$i++){
                foreach($funcionario_blocodcon as $key=>$val){


                    if($funcionario_blocodcon['localtrabalhodata'][$i]==""){ $localtrabalhodata = "00/00/0000"; } else { $localtrabalhodata = $funcionario_blocodcon['localtrabalhodata'][$i]; }
                    $localtrabalhodata = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($localtrabalhodata));
                    $funcionario_blocodcon_novo[$i]['localtrabalhodata'] = $localtrabalhodata;

                    if($funcionario_blocodcon['datademissao'][$i]==""){ $datademissao = "00/00/0000"; } else { $datademissao = $funcionario_blocodcon['datademissao'][$i]; }
                    $datademissao = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datademissao));
                    $funcionario_blocodcon_novo[$i]['datademissao'] = $datademissao;

                    $funcionario_blocodcon_novo[$i][$key]= $funcionario_blocodcon[$key][$i];
                    $funcionario_blocodcon_novo[$i]['idFuncionario'] = $ultimo_id;
                }
            }
```

Nele, eu preciso formatar  as datas que vem dos campos de data...
Mas o primeiro funciona normal e o segundo não.

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [localtrabalhodata] => 2015-12-07
            [datademissao] => 01/02/2015
            [localtrabalho] => 1
            [idFuncionario] => 102
            [segundaasextadas] => 08:00
            [segundaasextaas] => 10:00
            [sabadodas] => 18:00
            [sabadoas] => 00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [localtrabalhodata] => 2015-06-07
            [datademissao] => 01/05/2015
            [localtrabalho] => 13
            [idFuncionario] => 102
            [segundaasextadas] => 08:22
            [segundaasextaas] => 11:02
            [sabadodas] => 01:22
            [sabadoas] => 02:33
        )

)
```

O que tem de errado? Dá pra fazer de outra maneira?
Obrigado!

Comment: Para ajudar, coloque uma parte dos seus dados originais. Mas pelo que eu entendi o seu problema está nesta linha aqui: $funcionario_blocodcon_novo[$i][$key]= $funcionario_blocodcon[$key][$i]; - Observe que o $funcionario_blocodcon[$key][$i] vai deixar de funcionar pois o seu $id é o iterador mais externo e provavelmente não existe neste array.

Comment: Qual valor está vindo no campo `$funcionario_blocodcon['datademissao'][$i]` antes da formatação?

Comment: Vem o valor normal: 01/05/2015

Comment: Quando eu formato, defino ela na $datademissao ele retorna na tela: 2015-05-01, porém, na hora de inserir os dados, ele insere a que estava antes... tentei colocar a $datademissao_novo; como principal, pra definir o valor, de igual forma... não dá. O estranho que o primeiro tratamento do localtrabalhodata funciona certinho.... ...

Comment: Então na hora de exibir aparece no formato desejado? Você está usando o mesmo tipo de dados para os dois campos? Caso esteja usando o tipo datetime, a formatação no banco não é importante. Essa formatação só será mantida se você estiver salvando o dado como texto.

Comment: Estou usando DATE. Normal, yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Então vamos lá. Em que momento, realmente, você gostaria que a data aparecesse formatada e ela não está? Pelo que entendi em sua resposta anterior ela aparece na tela no formato desejado, porém é inserido no formato original. Você está vendo esse formato original quando a data é inserida no banco? Se sim, esse é o padrão do banco  e não interfere nos resultados da sua aplicação.

Comment: No banco de dados, como o formato é date, o retorno é: 0000-00-00, por isto, sei que ao inserir ela está indo como original... e também pelo debug que coloquei na questão que o resultado é no formato original

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25455/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-joel-rodrigues).